# Cross domain PHP or AJAX (or else) for use in dynamic banners

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, banner

my point is to create advertisment banner in a way, that it will be placed on someones server (say remoteserver.com) and still getting data, that I want to show from my server (say myserver.com).

That little issue, that bothers me, is how to do it. I have done some research, but obviously there are some restrictions about `php include` and maybe a little fewer about `AJAX calls` that goes cross-domains. But still I think I see those adds on the web every day.

And if possible the solution should mean anywhere from a few to none server configurations on remoteserver side.

Thank you very much.

/edit:
My original idealistic idea was to supply remoteserver with just `<div><?php include 'myurl'?></div>` and if anyhow possible I would love to stick to some simple solution like this, preferably using php.

Comment: Using an iframe is the most cross-browser solution and the most widely used solution for banner ads.

Comment: Will all remote servers that you serve banners to support PHP? if you use php, the server owner can modify said php before they include it. I definitely wouldn't include a similar ad in my php scripts without at least looking through it for malicious code.

Comment: ask the provider of remoteserver.com if you may have a subdomain

Comment: for ajax calls look into **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

Comment: Enable `Cross Origin Resource Sharing` and use `JSONP` to retrieve the banners. You'll need to establish an endpoint where when a certain security key is passed will return the JSON Object containing the AD information.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it is dangerous to recomend JSONP for beginners! It requires you to have stong end poin security

Comment: @KevinB I tried iframes and seems like there can't be anything easier :-). Am I getting it right?... simply paste url into iframe src and done... they are accessing my page actually.

Comment: @Marko to be honest, I cannot find sufficient info to make it work and about JSONP... I heard something about that, not trying it yet. And about me being a beginner... I admit that, but I am not that mad-not-caring beginner, so I am avare of security and willing to learn a lot of new stuff, since this really brings me joy :). Thank you for your advices, so far I will stick with iframes, if it does nto work, will try other things. Thanks

Comment: @Lukáš Řádek by beginner meant. Somebody who is new to spoken methods